# SyncFusion Xamarin.Forms Samples not building for iOS/Droid Projects

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I have VS 2015 Community with Xamarin, Android SDK, etc. installed and today I stumbled upon SyncFusions Controls for X.F that are free in the community license. I installed the SyncFusion Essentials Studio for Xamarin.Forms.

The problem is that I cant run the included Samples like SampleBrowser or ServerMonitor when I select Android or iOS. If I select UWP or WinPhone the apps run. 
The issue is that the projects do not build. In The SampleBrowser for example I get 1400+ Errors when I want to build. VS recognizes almost nothing of the Code. But as I said everything that is not a Droid/iOS Project runs.

I have the Android SDK installed with API 19-23. AVDs are also configured. I also have a Macbook Air next to me that is connected to VS.

I tried cleaning the solution and re-building the solution without success. There were also no changes to the code made.

Edit: Here is a picture of the error list:

[image]

Edit 2: Here is the error list from "build only" on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/w8JQehf4) and as an image:

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you should contact Syncfusion and tell them their samples are broken.  I'm not sure what you expect us to do for you.

Comment: I don't think that they would sell completely broken Samples for ~10k $. They are also a top partner of Xamarin. Thats why I think that something is wrong on my end.

Comment: I contacted SyncFusion now. Waiting for an answer.

Comment: Could you change the error filter to "Build" from "Build + Intellisense" to point out the actual error? The error filter combo box is available on top of the error list window.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I added the details above. @Prabakaran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The comment to only show "build" errors lead to the errorlist you see in Edit2. There you see an OutOfMemory-Error. The resolution is the following.

I copy the solution in case the site will go down. Source: http://www.kiwipiet.com/2016/05/javalangoutofmemoryerror-consider.html

"I was getting a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError while trying to compile a Xamarin Android application after adding HockeyApp.

I found to ways to resolve this.

The first option is to add a Environment Variable called _JAVA_OPTIONS and set it to -Xmx1g.  This sets the JVM heap size to 1GB.  You can either do this from the commandline by calling
SET _JAVA_OPTIONS = -Xmx1g
Or you can edit your system environment variables:"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The “java.lang.OutOfMemoryError” error is a Xamarin issue and it occurs when the app size is exceeded some limit. You can refer the following bug report.

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=18327

Solution:

Right click the Android project and select Properties > Android Options > Advanced

Set the Java Heap size as 1G.